# В чем разница и схожесть функции активации персептрона и Hinge Loss?

Tags: python, математика, машинное-обучение

Есть функция потерь Hinge Loss на графике она выглядит так красная пунктирная линия [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И функция активации персептрона выглядит похожим образом, только функции у Hinge Loss штрафует, даже есть мы правильно отвечает, а у функция активации персептрона мы перестаем это делать в нуле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый вопрос, почему функция потерь Hinge Loss продолжает штрафовать, даже если мы правильно ответили и таким образом менять веса, а у активации персептрона такого не происходит? Из-за чего это происходит? В чем разница и сходство этих функция?

Comment: В Википедии написано, что hinge loss для svm например применяется, в эту сторону нужно копать. Видимо, под них она заточена.

Comment: Hinge loss -это функция потерь, которая работает для классификатора на SVM, т.е. это как раз и подразумевает сдвиг на 1 шарнира. т.е. этот классификатор используется именно там, где предсказание события 1 имеет наиболее критическое значение, т.е. вы должны быть уверены на 100%.